# Filter grouped relation by changes in the group

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm yet another newbie with Pig Latin and hoping to get some assistance.

I have a data feed that looks more or less like this:

```
{ time:chararray, id:chararray, value:chararray }
{ '1:00', 'id1', 'value1' }
{ '1:00', 'id2', 'value2' }
{ '2:00', 'id1', 'value1' }
{ '2:00', 'id2', 'value4' }
{ '2:00', 'id3', 'value3' }
```

I want to get all the instances where the data changed between the time intervals. In this case:

```
{ '2:00', 'id2', 'value4' }
{ '2:00', 'id3', 'value3' }
```

I know how to do set subtraction between relations, but not between bags in a group. Keep in mind, I don't know what the values in the time field are (i.e., I don't know the values are '1:00' and '2:00'), just that they're a progression of times.

Comment: Is it sufficient to locate all of the IDs which are ever associated with more than one value?

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to track state changes (that's essentialy what the value field represents), so what's important is catching what's changed going from one time slice to the next.

Comment: I dont know any operation in pig which processes multiple rows at a time (except aggregate functions like Avg, Sum etc). You might want to write a UDF and pass all your data to the UDF.